# Buscar, modificar, eliminar y añadir a la base de datos con arraylist

Tags: java, jdbc

Quiero y estoy intentando en guardar los datos de la base de datos en un arraylist y luego poder usar el arraylist para modificar, eliminar, etc.

```
 public List<ClaseEmpresa> BuscarEmpresas() {
        List<ClaseEmpresa> empresas = new ArrayList<>();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM empresas";
        try  {
            con = conectar.getConnection();
            pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                ClaseEmpresa empresa = new ClaseEmpresa();
                empresa.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                empresa.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre_empresa"));
                empresa.setNif(rs.getInt("nit_empresa"));
                empresa.setDireccion(rs.getString("direccion"));
                // Agregar la empresa al ArrayList
                empresas.add(empresa);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return empresas;
    }

    public boolean eliminarEmpresa(int id, List<ClaseEmpresa> empresas) {
        String sqlDeleteEmpresa = "DELETE FROM empresas WHERE id = ?";

        try {
            con = conectar.getConnection();

            // Eliminar la empresa en la tabla "empresas"
            pst = con.prepareStatement(sqlDeleteEmpresa);
            pst.setInt(1, id);
            pst.executeUpdate();

            // Eliminar la empresa de la lista
            for (ClaseEmpresa empresa : empresas) {
                if (empresa.getId() == id) {
                    empresas.remove(empresa);
                    break;
                }
            }

            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean modificarEmpresa(ClaseEmpresa empresa) {
        String sqlempresa = "UPDATE empresas SET nombre_empresa = ?, nit_empresa = ?, direccion = ? WHERE id = ?";
        try {
            con = conectar.getConnection();
            pst = con.prepareStatement(sqlempresa);

            pst.setString(1, empresa.getNombre());
            pst.setInt(2, empresa.getNif());
            pst.setString(3, empresa.getDireccion());
            pst.setInt(4, empresa.getId());
            pst.executeUpdate();
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
    public boolean AddEmpresa(ClaseEmpresa empresa) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO empresas (id, nombre_empresa, nit_empresa, direccion) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        try {
            con = conectar.getConnection();

            pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setInt(1, empresa.getId());
            pst.setString(2, empresa.getNombre());
            pst.setInt(3, empresa.getNif());
            pst.setString(4, empresa.getDireccion());
            pst.executeUpdate();
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Esto es los codigos que tengo para buscar, eliminar, modificar y add.
Y esto es lo que tengo en los botones de la interfaz:

```
 btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int id = Integer.parseInt(inpID.getText());
                Empresa_SQL empresa = new Empresa_SQL();
                Oficina_SQL oficina = new Oficina_SQL();

                int confirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Estas seguro que quieres eliminar la empresa?","Confirmacion", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
                if (confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                    boolean oficinaEliminada = oficina.eliminarOficina(id);
                    if ( oficinaEliminada){
                        boolean empresaEliminada = empresa.eliminarEmpresa(id);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Empresa y oficina eliminadas correctamente");
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al eliminar la empresa");
                    }
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al eliminar la oficina asociada a la empresa");
                }
            }
        });
        btnEditar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int id = Integer.parseInt(inpID.getText());
                String nombre = inpNombre.getText();
                int nif = Integer.parseInt(inpNIF.getText());
                String direccion = inpDireccion.getText();
                int idOfi = Integer.parseInt(inpIDOficina.getText());
                String nombreOfi = inpNombreOfi.getText();
                int id_empresa = Integer.parseInt(inpIDOficina.getText());
                String direccionOfi = inpDireOfi.getText();

                ClaseOficina oficina = new ClaseOficina(idOfi, nombreOfi,id_empresa, direccionOfi);
                ClaseEmpresa empresa = new ClaseEmpresa(id, nombre, nif, direccion);

                Empresa_SQL empresaSql = new Empresa_SQL();
                Oficina_SQL oficina_sql = new Oficina_SQL();

                boolean empresaResult = empresaSql.modificarEmpresa(empresa);
                boolean oficinaResult = oficina_sql.modificarOficina(oficina);

                if (empresaResult && oficinaResult) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Empresa modificada correctamente", "Éxito", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al modificar la empresa", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });

        btnLimpiar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                limpiar();
            }
        });
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int id = Integer.parseInt(inpID.getText());
                String nombre = inpNombre.getText();
                int nif = Integer.parseInt(inpNIF.getText());
                String direccion = inpDireccion.getText();
                int idOfi = Integer.parseInt(inpIDOficina.getText());
                String nombreOfi = inpNombreOfi.getText();
                int id_empresa = Integer.parseInt(inpID.getText());
                String direccionOfi = inpDireOfi.getText();

                ClaseOficina oficina = new ClaseOficina(idOfi, nombreOfi,id_empresa, direccionOfi);
                ClaseEmpresa empresa = new ClaseEmpresa(id, nombre, nif, direccion);
                empresa.setOficina(oficina);

                Empresa_SQL empresaSql = new Empresa_SQL();
                Oficina_SQL oficinaSql = new Oficina_SQL();

                boolean resultEmpresa = empresaSql.AddEmpresa(empresa);
                boolean resultOfi = oficinaSql.addOficina(oficina);
                if (resultEmpresa && resultOfi) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Empresa guardada correctamente");
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al guardar la empresa");
                }
            }
        });
```

Me gastaría saber como hacerlo con arraylist. Ya que es la primera vez y no se como hacerlo el de buscar no se si estará bien tampoco. También tengo las clases oficina y empresa para los get y set. Y es que no soy capaz de meter dentro los datos de la base de datos al arraylist y luego modificar, editar, borrar y añadir.

Comment: que error estas obteniendo?

Comment: Quiero saber meter los datos de la base de datos a un arraylist estatico y por ejemplo añado una empresa y si se ha añadido en la base de datos se añada en el arraylist, si lo modifico lo mismo y si la elimino lo mismo.

Comment: con lo que intentaste que error te da?

Comment: No me lo hace no me lo actualiza el array ni modifica

Comment: Me piden un DBManager con todos los metodos de añadir, modificar, etc y un arraylist statico en el main. Y varias pantallas de swing. Entonces me pide que si añado se añada tambien en el arraylist

Comment: Hola, en el método asociado a **btnDelete** tienes las llamadas a **oficina.eliminarOficina( id )** y **oficina.eliminarEmpresa( id )**, no se de donde viene el código, pero me llama la atención, que el "id" no se recibe como parámetro, ni se pide... podrías poner un **System.out.print( id )** para ver que valor estás usando, y luego nos comentas.